# How to request botstate users on Microsoft Teams via Rest

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

If I send the Get request /v3/botstate/{channelId}/users/{userId} request to the emulator, it returns JSon. Nothing very useful of course since there aren't any real users in it. (doc referenced for the request https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/state/#/ and https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html#getsetproperties)

If I send it to Teams, I get a 500 Server error.  No additional information is returned with the error, it just repeats that there was a server error.
When I have gotten a 500 sending to Teams before, it was related to the JSon payload being sent.  In this case, there is no payload.
The request is in response to a "message" my bot received, and I am passing along the channelId and from.id from that "message" as my parameters.

I am able to send Post "message" requests back, and the Get request /v3/conversations{conversationId}/members successfully, so my Bot seems to be setup correctly.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Between yesterday and today things have changed.  The ServiceUrl use to have 'Skype' in the name, and now the ServiceUrl is 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/'.

Comment: Also, now instead of a 500 error, I get a 404 (not found) error when trying to get the user info.  The rest of it still works the same. Is this not ready for prime time yet?  It seems to be a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

- There was a temporary issue with Teams this week.  It has been fixed.
- The ServiceUrl is not guaranteed to stay the same.  It should be refreshed periodically.  Please see: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#connectorclient

> NOTE: Even though ServiceUrl values may seem stable bots should not
>   rely on that and instead always use the ServiceUrl value

As of today, the Bot Framework is still in preview.  The developers do their best to not commit breaking changes. The product is under continuous and active development. Thank you for your patience as the kinks are worked out.

[image: Bot Framework Preview]

Comment: I am getting 404 now instead of 500. From what I understand, you will not return any user information at this time, so I am guessing that is the best I can get right now.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams does not currently support retrieving user information beyond the ID returned in the members call, or the information received as part of incoming payloads.  We should have better support for this coming soon.